Let $G$ be a group, $H\unlhd G$. Does there always exist some group $G'$ with $G \le G'$ s.t. $H\not\unlhd G'$?
I might be missing something very trivial but I could not figure out an answer to this. There are two questions (two extremes).
Suppose $G$ is a group and $H \unlhd G$. Does there always exist some group $G'$ with $G \le G'$ that $H$ is no longer normal in $G'$?
Can you give me an example of a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that for some bigger group $G'$ with $G$ a subgroup of $G'$ we have $H$ is no longer a normal subgroup of $G'$?

You haven't provided context.

what context do you need?

Usually, question askers are expected to explain what they’ve tried and/or why they care about the question.

Your 2 questions are not "two extremes" since a yes to the 1st one implies a yes to the 2nd one. A anyway, please focus on a single question, and show some efforts on it.

The answer is yes, if $H$ is nontrivial.
Here are steps for one possible construction:

Embed $G$ into a symmetric group $Sym(\Omega)$.

By adding a point to $\Omega$, you can assume that $G$ fixes some $\omega \in \Omega$.

Prove that the only subgroup of $G$ that is normal in $Sym(\Omega)$ is the trivial subgroup.



This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

@Shaun: If you think the question is a duplicate, you can add a link to the duplicate in the comments. And if you think the question can be improved, you can give more specific suggestions in the comments. Meanwhile copypasted standard comments are not very helpful to anyone.

I did, @testaccount. See above.

What is $\Omega$?

@Kan't: The set that defines $Sym(\Omega)$. Here $Sym(\Omega)$ is the group formed by all bijections $\Omega \rightarrow \Omega$, i.e. the symmetric group on $\Omega$.

I'm well aware of that. But what's the connection between $\Omega$ and $G$?

I mesn, why not to take directly $\Omega=G$ and consider Cayley's embedding, for example?

@Kan't: It doesn't matter for the argument, it is just some set that $G$ acts on faithfully. As you say one possibility is the regular action on $\Omega = G$. In any case, the point of this answer was to give steps, not every single detail
